# I'm making a flashcard game but the "Next" button won't work

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm making a "Next" button to move onto the next flashcard in this game, but when I click on the button, nothing happens. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I'm using a lot of variables in this code, such as the number variable to state which question and answer it is. I tried adding one every time to the number variable, to change it to the next question, but it's not working.

```
    <div id="flashcard" onclick="flip()"><h1 id="word"></h1></div>
<br>
<button onlick="next()">Next</button>
<script>
var questions;
questions = ['artistic','daring','good','sports-minded','messy','disorganized','studious','funny','impacient','intelligent','neat','patient','lazy','shy','serious','nice','sociable','talented','hardworking','boy','girl','male friend','female friend','I','he','she','very','according to my family'];
var answers = ['artístico, artística','atrevido','bueno, buena','deportista','desordenado, desordenada','estudioso, estudiosa','gracioso, graciosa','impaciente','intelligente','ordenado, ordenada','paciente','perezoso, perezosa','reservado, reservada','serio, seria','simpático, simpática','sociable','talentoso, talentosa','trabajador, trabajadora','el chico','la chica','el amigo','la amiga','yo','él','ella','muy','según mi familia'];
var number = 0;
var answer = answers[number];
var word = questions[number];
var display = document.getElementById('word');
display.innerHTML = word;
function flip(){
if(word == questions[0]){
display.innerHTML = answer;
}
if (word == questions[1]){
display.innerHTML = answer;
}
if (word == questions[2]){
display.innerHTML = answer;
}
if (word == questions[3]){
display.innerHTML = answer;
}
if (word == questions[4]){
display.innerHTML = answer;
}
if (word == questions[5]){
display.innerHTML = answer;
}
if (word == questions[6]){
display.innerHTML = answer;
}
if (word == questions[7]){
display.innerHTML = answer;
}
if (word == questions[8]){
display.innerHTML = answer;
}
if (word == questions[9]){
display.innerHTML = answer;
}
if (word == questions[10]){
display.innerHTML = answer;
}
if (word == questions[11]){
display.innerHTML = answer;
}
if (word == questions[12]){
display.innerHTML = answer;
}
if (word == questions[13]){
display.innerHTML = answer;
}
if (word == questions[14]){
display.innerHTML = answer;
}
if (word == questions[15]){
display.innerHTML = answer;
}
if (word == questions[16]){
display.innerHTML = answer;
}
if (word == questions[17]){
display.innerHTML = answer;
}
if (word == questions[18]){
display.innerHTML = answer;
}
if (word == questions[19]){
display.innerHTML = answer;
}
if (word == questions[20]){
display.innerHTML = answer;
}
if (word == questions[21]){
display.innerHTML = answer;
}
if (word == questions[22]){
display.innerHTML = answer;
}
if (word == questions[23]){
display.innerHTML = answer;
}
if (word == questions[24]){
display.innerHTML = answer;
}
if (word == questions[25]){
display.innerHTML = answer;
}
if (word == questions[26]){
display.innerHTML = answer;
}
}
function next(){
number = number + 1;
display.innerHTML = word;
} //this is the function I need help on.
</script>
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Patrick+Hand+SC&display=swap');
#flashcard{
width:400;
height:250;
background:#fff555;
position:relative;
}
#word{
position:absolute;
transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
top:110px;
left:50%;
font-family: 'Patrick Hand SC', cursive;
}
</style>
```

What I want to happen is when the user clicks the "Next" button, it changes to the next flash card.

Comment: You’re not using the changed `number` in any way. `var word = questions[number];` doesn’t magically update if you update a different variable.

Comment: Okay, but then what do I do? I know it won't magically update

Comment: Just update it. `word = questions[number]` or replace the first line by `word = questions[number + 1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function could look like this. By the way you have a typo in `onlick="next()"`

```js
var questions;
questions = ['artistic', 'daring', 'good', 'sports-minded', 'messy', 'disorganized', 'studious', 'funny', 'impacient', 'intelligent', 'neat', 'patient', 'lazy', 'shy', 'serious', 'nice', 'sociable', 'talented', 'hardworking', 'boy', 'girl', 'male friend', 'female friend', 'I', 'he', 'she', 'very', 'according to my family'];
var answers = ['artístico, artística', 'atrevido', 'bueno, buena', 'deportista', 'desordenado, desordenada', 'estudioso, estudiosa', 'gracioso, graciosa', 'impaciente', 'intelligente', 'ordenado, ordenada', 'paciente', 'perezoso, perezosa', 'reservado, reservada', 'serio, seria', 'simpático, simpática', 'sociable', 'talentoso, talentosa', 'trabajador, trabajadora', 'el chico', 'la chica', 'el amigo', 'la amiga', 'yo', 'él', 'ella', 'muy', 'según mi familia'];
var number = 0;
var answer = answers[number];
var word = questions[number];
var display = document.getElementById('word');
display.innerHTML = word;
function flip() {
  if (word == questions[0]) {
    display.innerHTML = answer;
  }
  if (word == questions[1]) {
    display.innerHTML = answer;
  }
  if (word == questions[2]) {
    display.innerHTML = answer;
  }
  if (word == questions[3]) {
    display.innerHTML = answer;
  }
  if (word == questions[4]) {
    display.innerHTML = answer;
  }
  if (word == questions[5]) {
    display.innerHTML = answer;
  }
  if (word == questions[6]) {
    display.innerHTML = answer;
  }
  if (word == questions[7]) {
    display.innerHTML = answer;
  }
  if (word == questions[8]) {
    display.innerHTML = answer;
  }
  if (word == questions[9]) {
    display.innerHTML = answer;
  }
  if (word == questions[10]) {
    display.innerHTML = answer;
  }
  if (word == questions[11]) {
    display.innerHTML = answer;
  }
  if (word == questions[12]) {
    display.innerHTML = answer;
  }
  if (word == questions[13]) {
    display.innerHTML = answer;
  }
  if (word == questions[14]) {
    display.innerHTML = answer;
  }
  if (word == questions[15]) {
    display.innerHTML = answer;
  }
  if (word == questions[16]) {
    display.innerHTML = answer;
  }
  if (word == questions[17]) {
    display.innerHTML = answer;
  }
  if (word == questions[18]) {
    display.innerHTML = answer;
  }
  if (word == questions[19]) {
    display.innerHTML = answer;
  }
  if (word == questions[20]) {
    display.innerHTML = answer;
  }
  if (word == questions[21]) {
    display.innerHTML = answer;
  }
  if (word == questions[22]) {
    display.innerHTML = answer;
  }
  if (word == questions[23]) {
    display.innerHTML = answer;
  }
  if (word == questions[24]) {
    display.innerHTML = answer;
  }
  if (word == questions[25]) {
    display.innerHTML = answer;
  }
  if (word == questions[26]) {
    display.innerHTML = answer;
  }
}

function next() {
  number++;
  answer = answers[number];
  word = questions[number];
  display.innerHTML = word;
} //this is the function I need help on.
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Patrick+Hand+SC&display=swap');
#flashcard{
  width:400;
  height:250;
  background:#fff555;
  position:relative;
}
#word{
  position:absolute;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  top:110px;
  left:50%;
  font-family: 'Patrick Hand SC', cursive;
}
```

```html
<div id="flashcard" onclick="flip()"><h1 id="word"></h1></div>
<br>
<button onclick="next()">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code a lot if you use a variable to access the data in your array - you don't have to hard-code each index in your code. I think you want your code to work something like this:

```js
var questions;
questions = ['artistic', 'daring', 'good', 'sports-minded', 'messy', 'disorganized', 'studious', 'funny', 'impacient', 'intelligent', 'neat', 'patient', 'lazy', 'shy', 'serious', 'nice', 'sociable', 'talented', 'hardworking', 'boy', 'girl', 'male friend', 'female friend', 'I', 'he', 'she', 'very', 'according to my family'];
var answers = ['artístico, artística', 'atrevido', 'bueno, buena', 'deportista', 'desordenado, desordenada', 'estudioso, estudiosa', 'gracioso, graciosa', 'impaciente', 'intelligente', 'ordenado, ordenada', 'paciente', 'perezoso, perezosa', 'reservado, reservada', 'serio, seria', 'simpático, simpática', 'sociable', 'talentoso, talentosa', 'trabajador, trabajadora', 'el chico', 'la chica', 'el amigo', 'la amiga', 'yo', 'él', 'ella', 'muy', 'según mi familia'];

//Your code doesnt have to check every single index, just use a variable
var display = document.getElementById('word');
var next = document.getElementById('next');
let i = 0;

function flip(idx) {
  display.innerHTML = answers[idx];

  if (i < answers.length - 1) {
    //Increment the counter by 1 on each flip
    i += 1;
  } else {
    //Back to first card
    i = 0;
  }

}

//Flip the first card right away
flip(0);

//Add an event handler to the button to call flip when the button is clicked
next.addEventListener('click', () => {
  flip(i);
});
```

```html
<input type="button" id="next" value="Next">
<div id="word"></div>
```

Comment: This does not match the logic the OP asked for. But you are right there is big potential for reduction.